# Poisson maps in Hamiltonian PDEs (KdV in particular)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, hamilton-equations

I've run into a bit of a sticky point in doing some background research about the Hamiltonian structure of KdV.

What I know is:

A Poisson bracket is written in coordinates $x$ as $$\{F, G\} = (\nabla F)^T J(x) (\nabla G)$$

For some mapping $\phi: M \rightarrow M$, where $M$ is the manifold on which our dynamical system is defined, $\phi$ is a Poisson mapping if

$$\{F \circ \phi, G \circ \phi\} = \{F, G\}\circ \phi$$

This is all fine. But then, I have a source that says: The time map of a Hamiltonian dynamical system

$$\dot{x} = \{x, H\} = J(x)H(x)$$ is a Poisson map.

I don't understand what "the time map" is, or what it applies to. I see how the second equality above makes sense, and I see how KdV can be written as $\dot{u} = \{u, H(u)\}$, but I'm trying to make sense of what is being preserved exactly when I use a symplectic integrator, for example, or when I integrate in time.

Any clarification would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: The time map for a fixed $t$ is the map $M \to M$ given by $x(0) \mapsto x(t)$. Also note that for PDEs, you have Poisson maps on infinite-dimensional manifolds, while he coordinate expression you wrote is for finite-dimensional manifolds.

Comment: Yes, I see that there is a generalization for infinite dimensional manifolds. Regarding the time map, it isn't clear to me then how the time derivative is a map from initial data to time $$t$$. It seems like a time integrator is such a map, as it takes initial data and maps it forward in time.

Comment: That statement is not clear to me either. You can view the time map as a function of two variables: $(x(0),t) \mapsto x(t)$. I don't know if that helps.